# Raphael Drag + iPhone = Sad Camera App

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, raphael

Web app here:
http://www.digitaltransitions.com/visualizer/visualizer.html

Main javascript here:
http://www.digitaltransitions.com/visualizer/visualizer.js

### Relevant functions are at bottom of visualizer.js, named "dragger" "move" and "up".

I was a programmer a decade ago, and recently took it back up to help my company create a web app that helps our customers visualize how a specific lens will look on a specific camera.

Never mind the info wall (info request form); feel free to put in any garbage entries. Or you can add the function `unlock();` at the end of the `window.onload` and it will bypass the info wall screen and go straight into the app.

I've been very proud to get this far. But now I am majorly stuck and have been banging my head against the wall.

My web app passed testing on Mac_Safari, Mac_Chrome, Mac_Firefox. But it failed testing on an iPhone4s and iPad1; the sliders for focal length (the ##mm gizmo in the top right which changes how "zoomed" the lens is) do not function correctly. When the user grabs the slider some of the time it correctly slides back and forth, but other times it will jump to the far left of the screen at which point the app stops working at all.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

By the way, if you were wondering how to create a custom Google Docs Form with validation and a custom confirmation page I got my methodology from here:
http://www.morningcopy.com.au

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I would add some visual cue (such as horizontal line) to indicate that the sliders can be moved. I would not have realized that you can move the sliders if I had not read your question.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably do that!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your first job is to determine if this your bug, or Raphael's bug.  I'd start by switching out your "move" method with an empty method, and see what happens.

Another debugging approach would be to put a fixed-position div down in the corner of the page, and spit the x/y values into it, so you can see in real-time what the numbers look like.

I'd guess that you're running into a mathematical difference in how touch-points are calculated vs. how mouse-cursor-position is calculated.

Based on the hack you added, it looks like Raphael might be sending you a NaN value for Dx?